# selectbox doesn't change by ajax

Tags: ajax

I have ajax code that display the name of the cities(in selectbox) according the area that has been chosen:

```
<?PHP if ($_POST) { ?>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#areaID').filter(function(){
            var areaID=$('#areaID').val();
            var cityID=<?PHP echo $cityID ?>;
            $('#cityID').load('js/ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID+'&cityID=' + cityID);
            return false;
        });
    }); 
<?PHP }else { ?>

$(function () {
    function updateCitySelectBox() {
        var areaID = $('#areaID').val();
        $('#cityID').load('js/ajax/getCities.php?areaID=' + areaID);

        return false;
    }

    updateCitySelectBox();
    $('#areaID').change(updateCitySelectBox);
});
<?PHP } ?>
```

The problem is - after user submit the form and get error (i.e - forget to fill some field), user can change the area but the cities select box doesn't change according the new area.

What is wrong with the code?

```
<p><label>area</label> 
    <select name='areaID' id='areaID'>
        <?PHP
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `areas` ORDER BY id ASC "); 
        while($index = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $db_area_id = $index['id'];
            $db_area_name = $index['name'];
            if ($db_area_id == $areaID)
                echo "<option value='$db_area_id' selected>$db_area_name</option>";         
            else    
                echo "<option value='$db_area_id'>$db_area_name</option>";
        }
        ?>
    </select><span>*</span>
</p>

<p><label>City</label>
    <select id='cityID' name='cityID'>  </select>
</p>
```

Comment: What HTML code are you receiving from the ajax call?

Comment: in the city selectbox I see the same values that connect to the area value i chose before. but when I'm chossing new area, the city value doesn't change. I'm talking only after the first form submit

Comment: But the ajax call gives you some response, can you post the response that your getting from that call?